# Database design - Link a table to multiple tables (not always the same)

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a tool to help specific people track their work.
Each people makes interventions and during each one there may be some tests picked in a large range of tests. Each test has its own characteristics and they are quite distinct.

I cannot find a design that seems good. For now, I have this :

- A table for intervention
- A table for referencing the tests made and the common characteristics (kind of a parent class test).
- A table for each type of test with its own characteristics
- A type table to indicate all the type of tests

This looks like :

Interventions

- _id
- date
- user_id (Foreign key)

Tests

- _id
- intervention_id (FK)
- type_id (FK)
- generic_feature_a

Test_1

- _id
- test_id (FK)
- time_spent
- result_a

Test_2

- _id
- test_id (FK)
- result_b

...

Type

- _id
- test_name

This allow me to store all the data but this seems not good to make requests on it. For instance if I want to retrieve all the tests and the results associated I'd have to retrieve all the tests with the correct intervention_id (that is fine).
But for the results I'd have to use the previous query and for each test get the name of the test and make the request in the correct table.

I was also thinking to remove the generic table test and insert the intervention_id directly inside the specific test tables. But it becomes harder to get the list of all the tests...

Or do both and keep the generic test table and insert the intervention_id?

Any help on this ? 
Is there a better way to store data ? 
And if not, which of the 3 solutions seems the best to you ?

Thanks to you all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I kept the first schema. It allowed me to retrieve all the tests of a given user at once and drilldown if I need more information on the tests